# Generic Method for IDictionary<Tkey, Tvalue> - Type or namespace cannot be found?

Tags: generics, c#-4.0

```
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TVal> Insert(this IDictionary<TKey, TVal> dict, TKey key, TVal value)
    {
        dict.Add(key, value);
        return dict;
    }
```

I get my favorite red squiggly line under the `TKey` and `TVal` with the "Type or namespace cannot be found" error.  As placeholders for types, I wouldn't think this would happen... where am I screwing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type parameters to the method as well:

```
 public static IDictionary<TKey, TVal> Insert<TKey, TVal>(this IDictionary<TKey, TVal> dict, TKey key, TVal value)
```

to make it a generic method.

Comment: `<smack location="forehead">` Thanks `</smack>`